# Name rows with a character vector in R

Tags: r

I want to name the rows of a dataframe with a column of a second dataframe.
The dataframe to be named has the same number of rows as the dataframe I want to use for naming. Meaning the name of the ith row of the first dataframe shouldhave the name of the ith value of the column of the second dataframe.

I already tried the following:

```r
row.names(df1) <- as.character(df2[,1])
```

This results in all rows of df1 named after the first value in the vector of dataframe2.

Comment: Your current solution should work. Please provide example data, where this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```r
#Sample data
df
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5

df2
  a
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E

# Set row names
`rownames<-`(df, df2$a)

# Result
  a b
A 1 1
B 2 2
C 3 3
D 4 4
E 5 5
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately it still results in all rows being named with the first value.

Comment: Please provide your data and a sample of the code you have tried. According to my example it seems to work fine.